# COUNT column with an with an include and exclude in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server Table and I want to count id values if a specific value is exists.

The table looks like this:

[image]

For example I want to count `DRGPatientId` Where Code includes 'O82' but not does not include Code 'O342'.

Here is my sql code:

```
SELECT DONEM.DonemAdi AS Donem,COUNT(DISTINCT TIGC.DRGPatientId) AS DogumSayisi
                                    FROM [TIGTest].[dbo].[TIGPatient] TIGP
                                        ,[TIGTest].[dbo].[KART_DONEM] DONEM
                                        ,[TIGTest].[dbo].[Hospitals] HOST
                                        ,[TIGTest].[dbo].[TIGPatientCode] TIGC
                                    WHERE TIGC.Code IN ('O82') AND Code NOT IN ('O342')
                                          AND DONEM.DonemKodu=TIGP.Durum 
                                          AND TIGC.DRGPatientId=TIGP.Id
                                          AND TIGP.Sex='F'                       
                                    GROUP BY DONEM.DonemAdi ORDER BY  DONEM.DonemAdi ASC
```

As you can see on the table, Every DRGPatientID has multiple Code.So I want to count patient where Principal Diagnoses  '1' as 'O82' ,But it MUST couldnt exist 'O342' as additional diagnoses(2,3,..).

Comment: Can you elaborate on your desired output? As I feel my answer may not give you exactly what you want as none of those patients have those values in the screen grab. Do you want people grouped and only included if they have value1 and excluded if they have value2? Please add some sample data, covering different scenarios, along with desired output to illustrate the exact requirement.

Comment: use `like "%O82%"` instead `IN ('O82')`

Comment: I edited question for clear understand.Please check

Comment: @user3763026 as tanner asked, what would your expected output be ? This is important information

Answer (score 0):

use sql wildcards in where condition to check the code contains o82 in any place.
for ex

```
select * from tbname where code like "%O82%"
```